# How do I create a straight line with endpoints that track a curve when I rotate/move the line?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry, vector, lines

I would like move and rotate a line, but have the endpoints follow an elliptical curve. In the picture below, as I rotate the line, I want points A and B to stick to the curve.  Then as I move the line up or down on the z axis, the points still stick to the curve. I prefer to do it in geometry nodes if possible.

[image: Line with endpoints A & B and Curve]

Ultimately, I want to use the line endpoint x and z locations to create a second 'nested' ellipse whose major axis follows the curve as I move and rotate it. The third point for defining the nested ellipse will be an inputted y and z value where the line intersects the z axis (x=0).  Note I originally did this using a boolean intersection between a sphere (ellipsoid) and a plane, but it's behavior was a little erratic at times when you move the plane around.

Here's what I did so far using spheres as placeholder endpoints (might not need the actual line). Note the factor in the Modifier Properties is set to enter degrees. Not sure how to read the endpoint (spheres) location after rotating.

Here's the end result desired (done with boolean):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/.. following the instructions there, and editing the link into your post. Then we won't need access to your own storage. Please also illustrate the nested ellipse and its defining points?  Does the Y mean you're going into 3D?

Comment: Just updated link permissions so it can be shared.  Also, just realized I could connect the Sample Curve outputs direct to a Curve Line node to make the line.  Now need to figure out how to move it up and down.